# What error_code should the ReadHandler for boost::asio::async_read return when the stream is closed?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to implement the following for arbitrary streams (with both read and write interfaces).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html

What I plan to do is to pass the stream to some client. The client async_writes to the stream and when there is no more data it then closes the stream.

The calling code async_reads from the stream until I assume that it gets some indication of the stream close state via the ReadHandler error_code. My questions are:

1. What will this `error_code` be?
2. Can I guarantee to transmit all the data using this mechanism?
3. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: 2.: "Can I guarantee to transmit all the data using this mechanism?" - no, network is always susceptible to outage. Use a transactional message queue for this kind of requirement. 3.: Maybe. Message queuing might be what you want

Comment: What I meant by 2 is that. Once you write the last data and then call buffered_stream::close (for example), then subsequent reads on the other side will get the remaining data before the error code arising from the close.

Comment: My question may be specific to the buffered_stream::close that is provided, as this may provide my requirements. I am not sure what the typename Arg is for in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom line is: it depends on the implementation. If you want to abstract that interface away, I'd suggest abstracting the implementation details behind your own interface.

If you /want/ to expose the Asio interface (why?) then you *could* create a composed IO operation that translates all expectable errors to a common contract.

---

For specific implementations, a simple test would suffice of course.

For sockets, the usual error code is `eof` (`boost::asio::error::misc_errors::eof`). Depending on the circumstances `boost::asio::error::basic_errors::connection_reset` or `boost::asio::error::basic_errors::network_reset` could occur.

If the `io_service` is halted, the service object is destructed or the socket is closed, `boost::asio::error::basic_errors::operation_aborted` or `boost::asio::error::basic_errors::bad_descriptor` could be expected.

All these are implementation dependent, of course. Different platforms may have different codes, different streams may have different codes.

### Error Conditions

Instead of error codes you could try to make sure the error condition maps onto the same "thing" so clients will have a consistent interface.

- Chris Kohlhoff (author of Boost Asio) has an in-depth series of blog posts about this starting here http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/system-error-support-in-c0x-part-1.html
- Andrzej's C++ blog has another article that builds on it https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/07/12/your-own-error-code/